# How do I display a text box over a specific class of images in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

On my site I have an image class for external images. Every image MUST use the [caption] shortcode. I want to place a border and text box over every image in that class throughout the whole site.

So far I have...

```
.img-external {
     border: 5px solid #818a99;
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;  
     position: relative;
}
```

...shows up fine.

I want to add...

```
    .text-block {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
}
```

...with the text "EXTERNAL IMAGE"

This works...

```
if ($('.img-external')[0]) {
    $('.text-block').text('EXTERNAL IMAGE');
} else {}
```

...

```
<div class="img-external">
  <div class="text-block"></div>
</div>
```

...in theory when I plug it all into codepen but how can I make this work on Wordpress?

Edit: Wordpress is using `<figure><img class="img-external" src="">` etc., and I can't get it to work.  Where do I call the text-block?

Comment: Might just want to put that you're trying to get this to work with Word Press up the top. Just makes it easier to get people with the knowledge to help you.

Comment: How to dynamically create and insert/append a new element to the document using Jquery, is something you should be able to easily research yourself. You won’t be able to append this to `.img-external` in your WP output of course, because that’s an image, and images don’t have children. So you will need to insert it after the image, and then make the `figure` element relative positioned (so that it can serve as anchor point for the absolute positioned descendant.)

Comment: Thanks this is my first attempt at anything jquery and  it looks like I picked a hard one to try.  I might just place an image with the text over the img-external using css and study up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit yours template js and css file. Also you can add your file. More information you can find here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ and here: https://www.wpexplorer.com/javascript-wordpress/

Cheers

Comment: Thanks I'm more wondering how to change the syntax from the example with the divs.  That works for two empty divs but I need to somehow add a div somewhere or somehow call the text-box class.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if ($('.img-external')[0]) {
    $('.text-block').text('EXTERNAL IMAGE');
} else {}
```

to this:

```
if ($('.img-external')) {
        $('.img-external').first().find('.text-block').text('EXTERNAL IMAGE');
    } else {}
```

If you want add text only for first div with *.img-external* class

Cheers